# going through an A4Solution

Tags: api, alloy

I am currently using the Alloy api in my project, and I need to display A4Solutions.I can do that easily with the vizualiser Alloy provides (vizGUI) , but it is a bit too limited for my purpose. So I am willing to generate my own graphs ( using any other graph api ) from an A4Solution objects.

I was able to get the Atoms without any problems (that was pretty straight forward ) but I can't really see how to retrieve the relations between those atoms.

I looked online for some example about how to parse an A4Solution, but found nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relations, or fields, you can retrieve from sigs, and then you can evaluate them to obtains concrete atoms, something like this:

```
A4Solution sol = ...;
SafeList<Sig> sigs = sol.getAllReachableSigs();
for (Sig sig : sigs) {
  SafeList<Field> fields = sig.getFields();
  for (Field field : fields) {
    A4TupleSet ts = (A4TupleSet)(sol.eval(field));
    for(A4Tuple t: ts)
      for(int i=0; i<t.arity(); i++) 
        t.atom(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Was actually pretty straight forward ...

Thanks a lot for the quick support !