# How to store the Alloy solution into a desired Data structure?

Tags: alloy

I built an Alloy model and it successfully enumerated all the solutions I want. Each solution is a A4Solution object.

The output of each instance should be a simple Java POJO object, like the example below:

```
Class POJO {
int a;
int b;
String c;
boolean d;
}
```

My Alloy model basically generated all the possible combinations of the above 4 fields.

My question is that the A4Solution object is very complicated, how can I parse the object and store the generated fields into the POJO above?

Thanks

Comment: Also, when I try to add the Sigs to an ArrayList, it will through a NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15953327/1485337) for an example of how to iterate through an instance of `A4Solution` and extract atom values from it.